# ¿Cómo puedo ver los documentos a los que tengo acceso dentro de una máquina virtual?

Tags: ssh

Tengo un accesso con SSH a une maquina y quiero ver los PowerPoint:

```
me@sf01:/mnt/there/common/CU_Data/CU$ ls
 Code  'Description.pptx'   First_Sample_of_Dataset   Full_dataset   Models   test_image.jpg   Points.pptx
```

Por ejemplo quiero ver los powerpoint pero cuando intento abrirlos:

```
antoine.coppin@sb01:/mnt/confiance/common/CU_Data/CU$ Points.pptx 
Points.pptx : commande introuvable
```

Por lo mismo intento abrir un jupyter notebook:

```
me@sf01:/mnt/there/common/CU_Data/CU_Welding$ jupyter notebook
[I 23:15:19.251 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /home/me/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[I 23:15:19.445 NotebookApp] [jupyter_nbextensions_configurator] enabled 0.4.1
[I 2022-02-07 23:15:20.001 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jupyterlab
[I 2022-02-07 23:15:20.001 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab
[I 23:15:20.004 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /mnt/there/common/CU_Data/CU_Welding
[I 23:15:20.004 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.4.7 is running at:
[I 23:15:20.004 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=383ea46a0f8b56939917740b9d5d07a9127c02d3aa079856
[I 23:15:20.004 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=383ea46a0f8b56939917740b9d5d07a9127c02d3aa079856
[I 23:15:20.004 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 23:15:20.009 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
[C 23:15:20.009 NotebookApp] 
    
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/me/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-1366446-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=383ea46a0f8b56939917740b9d5d07a9127c02d3aa079856
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=383ea46a0f8b56939917740b9d5d07a9127c02d3aa079856
```

Peo no fue capaz abrir cualquier cosa en el browser de la mia maquina.

```
Host gitserve
  HostName host.name.fr
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/el_archivo_deidentidad
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  
Host gateway
  HostName host.name.com
  User me
Host VM_sf01
  HostName host.name-pf.ext
  User me
  ProxyCommand ssh -p 2001 -W %h:%p gateway
```

Comment: ¿Lo tienes montado en una carpeta local?  ¿O lo intentas ejecutar desde el servidor remoto via ssh?

Comment: Intento ejecutar desde el servidor remoto via ssh @masterguru . ¿Debo hacer otra cosa? O.o

Comment: Prueba mi respuesta a ver si te funciona

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, en una maquina remote puedes ejecutar los comandos del sistema remoto tal cual.

Luego, el error que tienes es porque no estás usando el programa adecuado. En uno de tus ejemplos, la computadora te muestra que el comando "Points.pptx", no existe:

```
Points.pptx : commande introuvable
```

Lo segundo (en el caso de tu aplicación de jupyter) es que estás tratando una máquina remota como si fuera tu máquina local. El explorador que se va a abrir es el de la remota. Si quieres abrir un explorador en tu máquina local, tendrías que, o redirigir el trafico de los datos del programa un puerto remoto al puerto local (con `ssh usuario@host -L <puerto local>:127.0.0.1:<puerto remoto>`, o `ssh usuario@host -D <puerto para la asignación dinámica>`), o ejecutar un utilizar el parametro `ssh -X`, para que los programas gráficos parezca que se ejecuten de forma local.

El problema con estas opciones es que estas correrían lento, porque cada dato que entre y salga, va a hacerlo pero encriptado con el algoritmo de encriptación que esté usando tu cliente de `ssh`.

Otra cosa que podrías hacer, es descargar tus archivos del sitio remoto a tu computadora personal usando sftp o ssh.

```
local> scp usuario@host:<ruta remota> <ruta local>
```

O:

```
local> sftp usuario@host:<ruta remote> <ruta local>
```

Answer (score -1):

Monta la carpeta remota usando `sshfs` en una carpeta local y podrás acceder a el como si lo tuvieras en tu dispositivo.

Por ejemplo:

```
sshfs usuario@servidor:/carpeta/remota/ /carpeta/local/
```

que en tu caso seria similar a esto:

**Nota:**  Primero crea la carpeta destino a montar, es decir, **/home/usuario/sshremoto/** antes de ejecutar la siguiente acción:

```
sshfs usuario@servidor:/mnt/there/common/CU_Data/CU_Welding/ /home/usuario/sshremoto/
```

Y luego, desde tu propio SSH o tu gestor de archivos gráfico puedes acceder a la carpeta `/home/usuario/sshremoto` y deberias podr verlo todo y manipularlo localmente. Otro tema seran los permisos de que dispongas, pero si no tienes demasiados en remoto quizas puedes copiarlos en local en otra parte y modificarlos.

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Pero como lo hizo cuand tengo un archivo de config como el que anadi en la mia pregunta ?

Comment: No lo se, la verdad, eso lo deberias haber especificado en la pregunta inicial. Mi solución era válida en determinado entornos, pero desconozco como aplicarlo en tu caso concreto, lo siento. Cuando hayas leido este comentario eliminaré mi respuesta.